# what is java.lang.Class<?>[]

Tags: java

What is `java.lang.Class<?>[]` in java . Specifically what is `<?>`.

I am a beginner in java , I cannot figure out what is the meaning of `<?>`

Thanks,

Puneet

Comment: Have you investigated/researched generics?

Comment: It's called a [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: this will help you : [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A type argument for a parameterized type is not limited to a concrete
>   class or interface. Java allows the use of type wildcards to serve as
>   type arguments for parameterized types. Wildcards are type arguments
>   in the form "?", possibly with an upper or lower bound. Given that the
>   exact type represented by a wildcard is unknown, restrictions are
>   placed on the type of methods that may be called on object of the
>   parameterized type.

Source:
[Generics In Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)
Also:
[Wildcards in Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: [This link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Generics) could provide even more info.

Answer (score 0):

Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application. The `<?>` part indicates that a Class can be a represantation of any java object, basicly. This is Java Generics.

Answer (score 0):

`<?>` means any type.

Since all java classes directly/indirectly inherit `Object`, you can simply think of `<?>` as `<Object>`, although this is not so precise.