# What does <?> mean in Android?

Tags: java, android

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id)
```

What is the meaning of `<?>` in the above code?

Comment: @0gravity: when brand-new users post questions that make no sense, it is often a good idea to hit the [edit] button and find out what they _wrote_ -- in this case, at least, pronay forgot to use the proper code formatting, so his `<?>` was interpreted as HTML and stripped -- making the question look silly. It's a simple fix, thankfully. :)

Comment: what you want to search for is "Java Wildcard". Take a look at [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/wildcards.html) example to get you started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is java.lang.Class<?>\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465277/what-is-java-lang-class)

Answer (score 1):

```
  Array<Int> arrayOfInts;
  Array<String> arrayOfStrings;
  Array<?>      arrayOfAnything;  // 

  Object o = arrayOfAnyting[0];
  if (arrayOfAnything[0] instanceof String){
    String s =(String) arrayOfAnything[0];

  }

 String s2 = arrayOfStrings[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`AdapterView<?>parent`

The `<?>` is a wildcard.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) to the docs for this particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

In the concept of Java generics it means you're using a wildcard.

So it means that any AdapterView type can be used in that signature.

Comment: what would the signature look like? ArrayListAdapter adapter could be passed in? or AdapterView<ArrayListAdpater> adapter might not be clear to reader.